# \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions border code works only on first physical page in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pgfpages

Borders will be drawn with `\pgfstroke` around all logical pages when compiling the following code with latex, pdflatex and lualatex:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=10mm,landscape]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfstroke}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfstroke}

\begin{document}
foobar \clearpage
foobar \clearpage
foobar \clearpage
foobar
\end{document}
```

When compiling with xelatex, though, the borders are drawn around the logical pages *only on the first page*.

But this works just fine even with xelatex if using `beamer`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=10mm,landscape]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfstroke}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfstroke}

\begin{document}
\frame{foobar}
\frame{foobar}
\frame{foobar}
\frame{foobar}
\end{document}
```

What is the exact trick/setting from `beamer` that need to be loaded for a normal `\documentclass{article}`, to make the borders work on all physical pages when compiling with xelatex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xelatex doesn't have a color stack, that means it looses color settings at page breaks. The border appears on all pages if you set the color explicitly:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=10mm,landscape]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\color{red}\pgfstroke}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\color{red}\pgfstroke}

\begin{document}\showoutput
foobar \clearpage foobar \clearpage foobar \clearpage foobar 
\end{document}
```

[image]